# Apache Spark: Map not running on node where data block reside

Tags: apache-spark, job-scheduling

I tried to run one of the regular [Java example](https://github.com/adobe-research/spark-cluster-deployment/blob/master/initial-deployment-puppet/modules/spark/files/spark/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java) from `Spark 1.4.1`.

**Settings**:

1. Three node hdfs cluster. The names are `master`, `slave1` & `slave2`.
2. Spark installed on all three nodes.
3. Job submitted from master by compiling and creating a jar of the example code as:

> ```
> ../bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 --class JavaWordCount temp.jar hdfs://master:54310/example/wordcount/data/test.txt
> ```

4. The input file, `example/wordcount/data/test.txt`, is barely ~ 1KB size with 9 lines. Checking on hdfs browser, the block containing this file resides on `Slave2`.
5. The example code is modified to print the IP address of the machine where the two map process (FlatMapFunction and mapToPair) runs.

Code snippet:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
      @Override
      public Iterable<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("FLATMAP Op " + s + " - on - " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() );
        return Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(s));
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("MAP2PAIR Op " +s + " - on - " + InetAddress.getLocalHost() );
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
      }
    });
```

**Observation**:
When I launch the application, I saw a randomness in the IP addresses where the maps are executing. I was expecting a deterministic result where the map will be executing on the `slave2` (because data block resides there), but sometimes it executed on `slave1` and sometimes on `master`.

Any explanation of this behavior? I am not using `yarn` manager.

Answer (score 0):

It is spark property . Spark can allocate to any machine which have more free resource . You can split file in partition then spark will assign task to every worker .

To make partition of file you have to give second argument into mapper part .

Comment: can you please back your statements with some reference to online documentation. It seems quite bizarre to move the data block from slave2 to slave1 or master and process there. Isn't it?